# Send faked socket.io request from the client to the server (node.js / socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm writing a web application and I've been thinking about security when working with sockets. Suppose there is a code on the client:

```
    $("#send").click(function(e) {
        var data = {
            name: "Albert",
            surname: "Einstein"
        };
        socket.emit("send data", data);
    }
```

Well, on the server it is somehow processed. The question is, is it possible to just simulate `socket.emit ("send data", data)` somehow, without a click, and with inserting my faked parameters to the `data`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can write a simple fake client example:

fake.js

```
const server = "127.0.0.1";  // change it to the address of your server
const port = 3000; // change it to the port of your server
const data = "I am a fake client";
const socket = require("socket.io-client")("http://" + server + ":" + port);

socket.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("connected");
    socket.emit("send data", data);
    console.log("data sent");
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fake",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

run `npm install` and then `node fake` and your mission is accomplished ;)